# how to remove time from date format in GROOVY

Tags: date, groovy

i have this

```
    def day1 =1
    def month1 = 10
    def year1 = 111
    render "a"

    def date1 = new Date(year1 ,month1, day1);
```

the output is

```
    Sat Oct 01 00:00:00 PKT 2011
```

the date is fine  , but can i remove this time format and country symbol i.e 01 00:00:00 PKT?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not "remove" it, TimeZone and Time are always part of the Date object.  You can, though, [print](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#getDateTimeString%28%29) [just](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format%28java.lang.String%29) the date portion.

```
groovy> def day1 =1 
groovy> def month1 = 10 
groovy> def year1 = 111 
groovy> def date1 = new Date(year1 ,month1, day1); 
groovy> print(date1.getDateString()) 
groovy> print("\n") 
groovy> print(date1.format("yyyy-MM-dd")) 

11/1/11
2011-11-01
```

Comment: There's also [#getDateString](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#getDateString()) which uses the [short](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#SHORT) date format from the system locale.

Comment: Link was dead, see https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#getDateString()

Answer (score 0):

As people keep telling you, you shouldn't use the `Date` constructor as it is deprecated.

A better Groovy example is:

```
def day1 =1
def month1 = 10
def year1 = 2011

String dateStr = Calendar.instance.with {
  set( year1, month1, day1 )
  format( 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
}
```